# Dotnet build working yesterday failing today

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, .net-core

I am using `dotnet build` to do a build of our .net core project which uses React and Webpack.  It was working perfectly yesterday, today...well it fails with the following error:

```
    EXEC : { error : Found '{' where a key name was expected (check your syntax or use quotes if the key name includes {}[],: or whitespace) at
line 1,1 >>>{ [c:\Code\blah\blah\blah.csproj]
    "compileOnSave" ...
EXEC : at error (c: \Code\blah\blah\node_modules\hjson\lib\hjson-parse.js:40:11) [c:\Code\blah\blah\Prom
appApiClient.csproj]
      at keyname (c:\Code\blah\blah\node_modules\hjson\lib\hjson-parse.js:158:9)
      at object (c:\Code\blah\blah\node_modules\hjson\lib\hjson-parse.js:356:15)
      at rootValue (c:\Code\blah\blah\node_modules\hjson\lib\hjson-parse.js:426:28)
      at module.exports (c:\Code\blah\blah\node_modules\hjson\lib\hjson-parse.js:444:10)
      at Object.parse (c:\Code\blah\blah\node_modules\hjson\lib\hjson.js:161:14)
      at ensureTsConfigContainsTypesEntry (c:\Code\blah\blah\node_modules\aspnet-webpack-react\scripts\postinstall.js:31:3
9)
      at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Code\blah\blah\node_modules\aspnet-webpack-react\scripts\postinstall.js:51:5)
      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10) hint: '' }

  > node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall c:\Code\blah\blah\node_modules\node-sass
  > node scripts/build.js
```

I have no idea where to look or what the error could possibly be, please someone help?!

Comment: Start by looking at your version control history and see what has changed in the code base.

Comment: I have done that already...no changes, was working on TeamCity yesterday and failing today, the git history shows "no changes", this made me prompt to test it locally and voila the issue existed locally too

Comment: Any changes to the build system (the O/S or any of the software involved)? Any change to NuGet (or other) types of dependencies?

Comment: Whenever you see an "error at line 1,1" be suspicious of that file. It could be empty, or locked, or have a null character at the beginning for some reason, that sort of thing.

Comment: We raised an issue https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1069 but still not sure about the solution.  @JohnWu: the project file has no changes so its not that file

Comment: It's an error of parsing the `JSON`. It can happen because of many reasons. For example, file encoding changed, or something similar. Or you really get your `JSON` configs corrupted.